# Why does -n followed by the -i switch in sed delete everything?

Tags: linux, shell-script, sed, arch-linux

I was trying to replace a word from multiple files in a directory with something else using the following `sed` command:

```
sed -n -i 's/pattern/replacement/g' "dir"/*
```

I was expecting that words inside my files matching the `pattern` will be replaced by my `replacement` word, but it did not, instead, all of the files inside `dir` was wiped out of their contents.

According to `sed's` manpage, `-n`, `--quiet`, `--silent` suppresses automatic printing of pattern space.

In my understanding, before `sed` processes a line of text, `sed` puts them first in the `pattern space` then `sed` applies a given command such as the substitution command `s///` **and then by default, prints out the resulting text**.

I thought, by using `-n`, I was only preventing `sed` from printing out any text to `stdout`, but I guess I was wrong and cost me important files I forgot to backup T_T

Comment: @HosseinVatani my pattern was just a simple word and nothing else. 's/localhost/local/g'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according `man sed`

```
-n, --quiet, --silent
     suppress automatic printing of pattern space
```

it is not useful way `sed` command.
you may use like this:

```
sed -n 's/pattern/replacement/p' "dir"/*
```

for printing.

```
sed -n -i 's/pattern/replacement/p' "dir"/*
```

to only save changed records

```
sed -i 's/pattern/replacement/g' "dir"/*
```

to change only matches records

Comment: But why though? I mean, if -n only suppresses automatic printing of pattern space then in my understanding, it doesn't have anything to do with processing or changing what's in the pattern space. If so, then why have an effect to the final output of the sed command?...

Comment: you should use _-n_ switch with _p_  because this switch **suppresses output**, _output_ means _outputting in any stdout_ .

Comment: could you please elaborate sir? because I am getting confused already..sorry.. My current understanding as I said from my question above is that the -n switch should prevent sed from printing out to stdout right? so if I am using -n to prevent the printing to stdout, then why would I need to use -p switch which forces sed to print into stdout??? Its like opting out of something because I don't want it but then opting in at the same time because I need... really sorry, I hope I am still making sense...

Comment: sorry if I could not explain clear. _stdout_ in linux could be terminal, file or ... .in `sed` command if you use _-i_, stdout would be the file, if you use not it _stdout_ (here) would be your terminal.then if you use _-n -i_ without _/p_ you tell to `sed`: ok!do my subsstitution and clear whole of file.if use _-i -n_ and _/p_ you say: do substitution and write only what effected. and ... more: not _-p_, _/p_.

Comment: sir thank you so much for your time, I really appreciate your effort to help someone like me. I understand it now, I wish I knew about this before I tried running that command on my files. thanks ^_^

Answer (score 4):

`sed` stands for "**s**tream **ed**itor". It is the streaming version of `ed` which is the *file editor*.

So, the way that `sed` is *intended* to be used, is that it always generates its output to stdout. *That's* the way the term "print" is used in the manual as well as in [the specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html).

`-i` is a *non-standard extension* for editing files that does not exist in all implementations of `sed` and is not guaranteed to behave the same in those implementations that *do* implement it. (For example, on my system, your command generates an error, because the backup file extension is *required*. I.e. on my system, I would have to specify something like `sed -n -i savemybutt 's/pattern/replacement/g' "dir"/*`, which would then backup each file `foo.txt` to `foo.txt.savemybutt` before editing.)

The fact that `-i` is both non-standard and a late afterthought means that the standard terminology in the documentation of your implementation of `sed` (I assume it is GNU sed) has never been changed, and thus it still uses the term "print" to mean "generate output" in the *general sense*.

In other words: in `sed`'s standard mode of operation, the *only way* of generating output is to print it to stdout. There is no way to edit files. Therefore, in the standard mode of operation, printing and outputting are the same. Once you add `-i` into the mix, things get murkier, but "print" *still* means "generate output" in the *general sense* even if the output is going to a file, because that's what "print" has *always* meant.

The *intention* of `-n` is that it *only* generates output that you explicitly print, for example by using the `p` command:

```sh
sed -n '/<body>/,/<\/body/p' < some_html_document.html
```

This will print (roughly) the `body` element of an HTML document. (This is a stupid example, of course.)

Comment: I can't work out what the `,` is for. Is it correct? And can you use a different separator to avoid escaping the `/`?

Comment: That's just the way you give addresses: `starting-line,ending-line`.

Comment: Yes, you could use a different delimiter, but to specify that it is a delimiter, it would need to be preceded by a backslash, so it wouldn't buy us much, we just move the backslash from one place to another. E.g. `sed -n '/<body>/,\@</body@p' < some_html_document.html`.

Comment: Note, all of this is explained in the specification I linked to in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your description of `-n` seem spot on. However you seem less clear on `-i`.

The normal behaviour is to output to stdout. so "I thought, by using -n, I was only preventing sed from printing out any text to stdout" would mean stop it doing its job.

Then `-i` changes the behaviour to do it in place. But some result.

## How to avoid in the future

Next time test without the `-i`. So output goes to stdout: No mutations happen. (functional programming (no mutations) is safer than procedural).

And don't write code unless you have a failing test. (do you have anything going to stdout that is causing a problem?)

Comment: yeah, I learned that the hard way... I felt confident using sed that I thought its -n switch would not do me any harm...